# Principled BSDF node not shading right

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

I'm trying to texture and shade this archway I have but its not rendering correctly. I added a basic cube mesh and set up BSDF nodes exactly how I have them on my archway and it comes out perfect.

Why isnt it working on the object I created? I've used [blendergurus video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUl3GvT92T8&t=380s) on the subject to set up the nodes so you know the exact steps I have taken.

Here is the Basic cube(how I want it to show up) and then  the archway I want shaded. notice the color is one solid shade of grey with no brown specs?

Can anyone help me find the problem here?

[image: Here is the Basic cube(how I want it to show up)] 
[image: And here is the archway I want shaded. notice the color is one solid shade]

Comment: Do you unwrap the ark?

Answer (score 2):

You need to unwrap your model. In edit mode select all vertexes and press <kbd>U</kbd> -> Smart UV project. It will creates very basic UV for you, if you want go farther, study UV unwraping.

Comment: Thanks drove to the store after posting this question and remembered that it has to be unwrapped lol thanks anyway. hopefully this can help someone else in the future